# Sending POST request using PHP - Failure

Tags: php, post

I was looking for a way to send POST request with headers and content in PHP, and I have found a great solution posted here on stackoverflow, here is code:

```
<?php
$uid1 = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 8)), 0, 8);
$uid2 = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 4)), 0, 4);
$uid3 = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 4)), 0, 4);
$uid4 = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 4)), 0, 4);
$uid5 = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 12)), 0, 12);
$uid6 = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", 1)), 0, 1);
$randuid = ("demo."."00000000"."-".$uid2."-".$uid3."-".$uid4."-".$uid5);
$url = 'https://www.something.com/rest/client/users/ticket/demo';
$data = array('password' => 'demo', 'deviceUid' => $randuid, 'deviceModelId' => '14');
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);

?>
```

I got perfectly good response, but when I try for second time i get nothing. When I change my IP address, i positive response again, and then again for a second time it won't work.
It gives me following error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily > > Unavailable

BUT When I do post request on http://requestmaker.com/
I sent over 1000 requests on this site and it worked flawlessly every single time.
What this guy did is awesome, as far I know, this file is sending requests
http://requestmaker.com/requester.php but no more information there.
He is not sending requests from new ip address every time because that is not possible.
What is secret of this developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

503 means the functions are working but you're getting a response from the server denying access. If you ever tried to cURL google results the same thing happens, because they can detect the user-agent used by file_get_contents and cURL and as a result block those user agents.

Mainly three common reasons why the commands wouldn't work:

1. The default USER-AGENT has been blocked.
2. Your server's IP block has been blocked.
3. Remote host has a proxy detection.

I was also in a situation like this but all I did was add the `User-Agent` header and set it to the user agent of the browser I'm using. For example something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

This might work:

```
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n; User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    )
);
```

Comment: Why then first requests always succeed?
LIke it has some time limit, if i refresh every 20 seconds it works every time, but it seems like to block me when i refresh too many times.
But this guy achieved it (url i mentioned above) i sent over 30 requests in a minute.
HOW

Comment: I tried user agent, won't work.
request maker is not sending user agent...

Comment: @Darktwen Many websites have something called DDoS protection which helps protect them from large amounts of traffic from overwhelming their servers. The time limit is there to stop to much traffic from reaching their webpage. There are many ways he could have increased the number of requests he made, one way could be that he has many IP addresses to distribute the requests. Another possibility is that he scrubs his cookie data after every post. I have had to deal with this kind of thing before and trust me - its not easy.

Comment: @Darktwen What exactly is this for by the way? why would you want to access a webpage THAT frequently?

Comment: Because it gives me my video urls so i can watch them without accessing client area.
They said me to send post request at given address and then i get token as answer which i use, and i need new one every time i access new video.
LOng story...

Comment: It is crazy to me because it worked fine for a long time, perhaps they changed something or set some limit, i do not know what to do.
Maybe to put sleep(60); before script?
SO i not reach limit

Comment: @Darktwen Probably something like that, if it used to work but doesn't anymore then they must have changed something. Like I said, 503 means an error happened on THEIR side not yours. If you can access them every 20 seconds then maybe `sleep(20)`. Otherwise, you would have to do some IP shenanigans like routing through a proxy network or somehow changing your IP between every request.

Comment: @Darktewn Its perfectly do-able but think about it like changing your identity every time you wanted to go overseas. Its a pain in the ass to do but its still do-able.

Comment: What if i just add text file with 100 working proxy server ips and ports, and then in post header add proxy and use it randomly.
Would that work?

Comment: @Darktwen If you can find proxy server IPs like that then yes that would proably work.